# Protecting files?

Tags: authentication, content-management-system, keystonejs

Can I have a permissions-managed list of files in KeystoneJS in which not only the list is protected (let's say I have a list of PDFs on a page that only logged-in users can see) but the files themselves are as well? For example, if I have a list of PDFs on a password-protected page, if I copy the URL of one of those PDFs to a separate browser and paste it in, will I be able to access that file since I'm not logged in?

Currently, ApostropheCMS seems to do what I need it to as far as handling files as content well, permissions, etc., but there is no built-in way to protect the files themselves. Would be great if there was a way in Keystone to accomplish this.

Comment: Are these files in your database at all, or are they being served from some folder using Express? [This related Keystone GitHub issue](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/2661) may shed some light on a solution. They use Amazon S3 to manage files, but you could conceivably do the same thing using `Types.File` and the Local File adapter (Keystone 4).

Comment: Actually don't have any yet. I'm trying to figure out if Keystone or Apostrophe is going to do what I need it to do, which is basically:

- document management
- web content management
- group/role based permissions to certain files/content
- easy to use and make edits (since my users are not very savvy)

Comment: Keystone doesn't have too much in the way of role/permission management, unfortunately. Unless you want to develop your own role system to be used on User models in Keystone, there isn't an out-of-the-box solution with Keystone other than something binary (e.g. can or can't do something). Multiple roles for users aren't impossible, but they have to be developed for the use case you need.